# Working of hibernate. Is it necessary to use transaction every time? Will it cause any issue if i dont use it while retieving data?

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I wrote the below code to retrieve data from the data base, in that do we need to begin the transaction? Because it runs without any issue. Is it necessary to use it every time? Will it cause any problem in future without that?

```
public static Student getStudentById(long id) {
    Session session = null;
    Student student = null;
    //Transaction transaction=null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        //transaction = session.getTransaction();
        //transaction.begin();
        /**
         * names in the query should match the related class name and variable names.
         */
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Student where studentId = :id");
        query.setLong("id", id);
        student = (Student) query.uniqueResult();
        //transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        //transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return student;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to use transaction unless and until you are planning to persist the data inside the db. And In your question you are not persisting the date you are just fetching the records from the db. So here not mandatory to use transaction.

Comment: If you have a process that does several selects to the database over a longer period of time and you need to have a consistent view of the database for that, transactions (e.g. a serializable) do make sense for read-only scenarios.

Answer (score 8):

According to hibernate documentation Database, or system, transaction boundaries are always necessary. No communication with the database can occur outside of a database transaction (this seems to confuse many developers who are used to the auto-commit mode). **Always use clear transaction boundaries, even for read-only operations**. Depending on your isolation level and database capabilities this might not be required, **but there is no downside if you always demarcate transactions explicitly**. Certainly, a single database transaction is going to perform better than many small transactions, even for reading data.

You can refer [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation) here.

Comment: actually this should be the accepted answer. Without auto-commit, you would get an exception trying to load something without an active transaction.